# Populate hidden field with the last selected value using angular.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

So, I have this code [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheko_elanteko/kr4mA/2/)

```
<div ng-app="testApp">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form>
        <p>
            <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="i.name for i in items"></select>
        </p>
        <p ng-show="selectedItem.subItems">
            <select ng-model="selectedSubItem" ng-options="i.name for i in selectedItem.subItems"></select>
        </p>

        <p ng-show="selectedSubItem.subItems">
            <select ng-model="selectedSubSubItem" ng-options="i.name for i in selectedSubItem.subItems"></select>
        </p>

        <input type="hidden" name="selection" value="????">

        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

</div>
```

And in that code I only show the next dropdown if the selected item has a child array.
Now, I want to populate the value of the hidden field with the last selected value of that dropdown chain using Angular.js.

In another word, if the user chooses an option in the last dropdown that appear, I want that hidden field at the end to have that value to be submitted with the form.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may do, if the length of the chain is fixed:

```
<input type="hidden" name="selection"
    value="{{ (selectedSubSubItem || selectedSubItem || selectedItem).name }}"/>
```

To solve the problem with going backwards to the chain, a simple solution is to use `ng-change` and nullify all the next values, i.e.:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="i.name for i in items"
    ng-change="selectedSubItem=null;selectedSubSubItem=null"></select>
```

See forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zH77p/1/

---

Alternatively to the `ng-change`, you can use watches in the scope; the advantage is that the watches only need to know their immediate child:

```
$scope.$watch("selectedItem", function(newval, oldval) {
    if( newval !== oldval ) $scope.selectedSubItem = null;
});
$scope.$watch("selectedSubItem", function(newval, oldval) {
    if( newval !== oldval ) $scope.selectedSubSubItem = null;
});
```

Comment: That works going forward in the chain, but when going backward it's stuck at the last value.

Comment: That works well, It works when going backward in the chain, but if I'm at the last option and changed the very first option, it's stuck again, I would have to go back in the chain one by one in order to work properly.

Comment: Did you implement the `ng-change` as above i.e. changing the 1st nullifies the next **two**, changing the 2nd nullifies the third? In the provided fiddle, changing the 1st after selecting all the way to the 3rd works correctly. And the watches work too. What are the exact steps you tried - in case I have not understood your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
<input type="hidden" name="selection" value="{{selectedSubSubItem.name}}">
```

The two-way binding will update the value of the hidden input once the value of the respective `select` gets changed.

If you want to get it dynamically based on the last selected:

```
<input type="hidden" name="selection" value="{{selectedSubSubItem.name || selectedSubItem.name || selectedItem.name}}">
```

If you want to be able to go back in the chain this will help. But I strongly recommend to move this logic to the controller:

```
<input type="hidden" name="selection" value="{{(selectedSubItem.subItems ? selectedSubSubItem.name : false) || (selectedItem.subItems ? selectedSubItem.name : false) || selectedItem.name}}">
```

Comment: But that only populate the hidden field with the very last value of the chain.
I want to populate the hidden field with whatever is the last value the user selected.

Comment: @user1706198 ok, that wasn't clear. But it is easy to accomplish (see update).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are interested in this type of "chained selection", you need to use some more complex logic.
Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2Az4P/3/
I used ng-value, but you can leave your value and set it to

```
value="{{choiceValue()}}
```

which would have the same effect.
What I did was to make the answers in an array (`selectedItem = []`) and then populate it as I go along (notice the `ng-model` of each selection).

On each selection, the value updates accordingly using the function `choiceValue()` which updates the `ng-value` accordingly.

This way, you can add as many selections to the chain, and just update their number (actually, you could use `ng-repeat` for this, and use the `$index` to automatically create more choice levels).

It's a bit more work, but you can see the basics here:
http://jsfiddle.net/brendanowen/uXbn6/8/

It all depends how complex/automated you need to do this :)

Comment: That works, but it fails to show the third dropdown in the chain for some reason.

Comment: That's very useful.
But why in the first fiddle, only the second dropdown appear and not the third?

Comment: I've updated the fiddle. I had a typo in the variable name.  This is why using the ng-repeat to create the series of selects could be very handy - not much to type, so less chance of typos :)

Comment: There's a problem when choosing the last item "sub sub item 2" and jumping up to the very first dropdown in the chain and choosing "item 1", the value get stuck at "sub sub item 2", also the second dropdown don't disappear!!